# How to make After Effects quit after passing -r javascript from command line

Tags: java, javascript, after-effects

While passing JavaScript `myScript.jsx` to After Effects I want After Effects to exit on completion:

"C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe After Effects CC\Support Files\AfterFX" -r   "C:\Workspaces\MyAEScripts\myScript.jsx"

So the very last line in passed JavaScript myScript.jsx script is:

```
app.quit();
```

Regardless of this command After Effects just doesn't want to quit. I have tried to include an

```
app.exitAfterLaunchAndEval=true;
```

but that didn't help.

If I would pass the same javaScript but using

`AfterEffects.exe -s "here is same javascript ending with; app.quit();"`

it exits (quits) beautifully.

I would stay with passing javascript (using `-r`). But there is a limit on how many characters can be used on a command line in Windows. 
I need to be able to make After Effects to exit after it is finished running script passed with `-r c:/path/to/myJavaScript.jsx`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

had the same problem you are describing because the project has changed and the app is waiting for your response on whether to save it or not.

legendary Dan Ebberts suggests adding:

```
app.project.close(CloseOptions.DO_NOT_SAVE_CHANGES);
app.quit();
```

works for me

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes these two commands dont work.

```
app.project.close(CloseOptions.DO_NOT_SAVE_CHANGES);
app.quit();
```

So here is another solution that works on Windows

```
var killAeCommand = "TASKKILL /F /IM AfterFX.exe"; 
system.callSystem("cmd /c \"" + killAeCommand + "\"")
```

Im not sure but I think that this command will kill all AE instances, in my case works fine because I only have one open.